# PostScript to PDF conversion/slow print issue [GhostScript]

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

I have several large PDF reports (>500 pages) with grid lines and background shading overlay that I converted from postscript using GhostScript's ps2pdf in a batch process.  The PDFs that get created look perfect in the Adobe Reader.

However, when I go to print the PDF from Adobe Reader I get about 4-5 ppm from our Dell laser printer with long, 10+ second pauses between each page.  The same report PDF generated from another proprietary process (not GhostScript) yeilds a fast 25+ ppm on the same printer.

The PDF file sizes on both are nearly the same at around 1.5 MB each, but when I print both versions of the PDF to file (i.e. postscript), the GhostScript generated PDF postscript output is about 5 times larger than that of the other (2.7 mil lines vs 675K) or 48 MB vs 9 MB.  Looking at the GhostScript output, I see that the background pattern for the grid lines/shading (referenced by "/PatternType1" tag) is defined many thousands of times throughout the file, where it is only defined once in the other PDF output.  I believe this constant re-defining of the background pattern is what is bogging down the printer.

Is there a switch/setting to force GhostScript to only define a pattern/image only once?  I've tried using the -r and -dPdfsettings=/print switches with no relief.

Comment: Why don't you print the original PostScript then? Also printer CPUs may be slow. You could try to rasterize the pages using Ghostscript and then send the raster images to the printer.

Answer (score 1):

Patterns (and indeed images) and many other constructs should only be emitted once, you don't need to do anything to have this happen.

Forms, however, do not get reused, and its possible that this is the source of your actual problem. As Kurt Pfiefle says above its not possible to tell without seeing a file which causes the problem.

You could raise a bug report at http://bubgs.ghostscript.com which will give you the opportunity to attach a file. If you do this please do *NOT* attach a > 500 page file, it would be appreciated if you would try to find the time to create a smaller file which shows the same kind of size inflation.

Without seeing the PostScript file I can't make any suggestions at all.

Comment: I've created a bug report and tried attaching some sample files that do recreate the problem, but for some reason it would not allow me to attache the files.  Still trying to figure out how to get the files uploaded.  In the meantime, your suggestion about forms seems to be more accurate as I am actually embedding a form definition at the top of my post script file.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at the source PostScript now, and as suspected the problem is indeed the use of a form. This is a comparatively unusual area of PostScript, and its even more unusual to see it actually being used properly.

Because its rare usage, we haven't any impetus to implement the feature to preserve forms in the output PDF, and this is what results in the large PDF. The way the pattern is defined inside the form doesn't help either. You could try defining the pattern separately, at least that way pdfwrite might be able to detect the multiple pattern usage and only emit it once (the pattern contains an imagemask so this may be worthwhile).

This construction:

```
GS C20 setpattern 384 151 32 1024 RF GR
GS C20 setpattern 384 1175 32 1024 RF GR
```

is inefficient, you keep re-instantiating the pattern, which is expensive, this:

```
GS C20 setpattern 
384 151 32 1024 RF
384 1175 32 1024 RF 
GR
```

is more efficient

In any event, there's nothing you can do with pdfwrite to really reduce this problem.

Answer (score 0):

*'[...] when I print both versions of the PDF to file (i.e. postscript), the GhostScript generated PDF postscript output is about 5 times larger than that of the other (2.7 mil lines vs 675K) or 48 MB vs 9 MB.'*

- **Which version** of Ghostscript do you use? (Try `gs -v` or `gswin32c.exe -v` or `gswin64c.exe -v` to find out.)
- **How** exactly do you 'print to file' the PDFs? (Which OS platform, which application, which kind of settings?)

Also, `ps2pdf` may not be your best option for the batch process. It's a small shell/batch script anyway, which internally calls a Ghostscript command.

Using Ghostscript directly will give you much more control over the result (though its commandline 'usability' is rather inconvenient and awkward -- that's why tools like `ps2pdf` are so popular...).

Lastly, without direct access to one of your PS input samples for testing (as well as the PDF generated by the proprietary converter) it will not be easy to come up with good suggestions.

Comment: The version is 9.04 running on Win 2008 server (x64), but i can recreate on my desktop which is win 7 Ult. x64.  Also, on the server, i use a C# wrapper call to gswin32.dll, I used ps2pdf for a quick test, but result was same.

Comment: In Adobe Reader, there is an option "Print To File", which writes the output to a postscript file.

Comment: @user1535044: I asked for '*which kind of settings*', and I asked that for a reason: You can select different PostScript language levels, you can tell AcroRead to 'download Asiatic fonts' or to 'convert TrueType fonts to Type1', you can 'print as image' and much more....

Comment: Language: Level 3, Color Management: Treat grays as K-only grays +  Preserve Black, Font Resource Policy: Send at Start,  Download Asian fonts: Not checked